# split string on comma, but not commas inside parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Now  I have a task about Java IO , I need to read file line by line and save this data into database, But Now I got a problem.

```
"desk","12","15"，"(small,median,large)"
```

I want to use `string.split(",")` to split by , and save data  into each column. But I found that the data in the () has also been split, I do not want to split (small, median, large) and I want to keep this  integrity. How can I do that? I know I can use regualr expression , but I really do not know how to do  it?

Comment: You'd probably better use a CSV parser than a regex.

Comment: Use a [Java CSV Reader](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+reader).

Comment: Following `Robert Harvey♦`'s suggestion: see http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html

Answer (score 0):

or, if Java must be:), you can split by "\\s*\"\\s*,\\s*\"" and add afterwards the " if necessary to the beginning of the first field and to the end of the second.
I put \s because I see that you also have blanks separators - 15",blank"(small

Comment: if one is String  is  "desk",12,15,"(small,median,big)",,"price"  could help me find a split solution , thank you....

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using `Pattern` and `Matcher`. Any solution using split would just seem like a nasty workaround. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "\"desk\",\"12\",\"15\",\"(small,median,large)\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\".+?\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (m.find()){
        matches.add(m.group());
    }

    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Comment: I can not change the string... What I can do is to use the original string. How can do it ?

Comment: Your original String will be fine, I only added the escapes because I compiled the String in Java code. My example's String and yours are equivalent. However, if you want you can edit your post to show how you acquire the String, and I can edit my answer

Comment: 608,7283,611,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,"3.3","Model","Model (CHILD, ADULT, PARTNER...)",,0,0,"U",2,0,0,,,"Enter new model under DESCRIPTION",,0,"DeskModel","LMSyr Part Actions","< None >",50    you can see there is (CHILD,ADULT,PARTNER...) when I split it use it , it will split this

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the value even when it's just an empty text between commas? Or can those be ignored?

Comment: Yeah , I use Java Beans to load the data , so I need to know which is empty. So That is why I use split function.  My idea is when I encounter "(,,,)" I replace string in it to another like . or ? then split.. Or Do you have better idea?

Comment: I'm sorry. It is definitely doable, but the code would be very very ugly. Have you tried the CSV reader other people suggested?

Comment: No ,Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Hi Sorry to bother you again...  If I change the string into   desk,12,15,,(small,median,large). Do you have any solution about this？

Comment: Not really, what would help is for you to find a different delimiter, one that never appears on your String, so that you could split it without having problems

Comment: *don't* use the regex in this code. The methods are correct but that regex is too hard coded unless you only want to match desk, 12, 15 and those sizes. and if that is the case don't use regex just place the correct values in where ever you need

Answer (score 0):

```
(\(.+?\)|\w+)
```

the code above matches the result below this will allow for a more flexible solution that some of the other posted ones. The syntax for the regular expression is in another answer on this page just use this regular expression instead

desk
12
15
(small,median,large)